# Existence of parametrization with dense image for an invariant surface in $\Bbb R^4_1$.

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, symmetry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am trying to read the paper [Boost invariant marginally trapped surfaces in Minkowski $4$-space](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/24/22/009/pdf), by Haesen and Ortega. Basically, they work with metric signature $(-+++)$ in $\Bbb R^4_1$, consider the group of boosts $$G = \{  R^h_\theta\oplus {\rm Id}_2 \mid \theta \in \Bbb R  \},$$where $R^h_\theta \in {\rm O}_1^{+\uparrow}(2,\Bbb R)$ denotes hyperbolic rotation by $\theta$, and they claim that if $S \subseteq \Bbb R^4_1$ is a **connected** spacelike surface which is invariant by the action of $G$ in $\Bbb R^4_1$, then $S$ admits a parametrization $X\colon I \times \Bbb R \to \Sigma_\alpha \subseteq S$ of the form $$X(s,\theta) = B_\theta(\alpha(s))$$for some open interval $I\subseteq \Bbb R$, *where the image $\Sigma_\alpha$ is an open dense subset of $S$*.

> I can't check that such a parametrization is always available, let alone prove that the image is dense in $S$.

They mention that the set of fixed points of the action is $\{(0,0)\} \times \Bbb R^2$ very near of that claim, so I think this should be useful. Please help.

---

**Edit 1**: I think I can convince myself why the parametrization has that form. If you take $(x,y,z,w) \in S$, since $S$ is invariant, we can write $(x(s),y(s)) = (\alpha_1(s)\sinh \theta, \alpha_1(s)\cosh\theta)$, assuming that $S \subseteq \mathcal{R}$. Since $\dim S = 2$, $z$ and $w$ can only depend on one parameter, which obviously cannot be $\theta$. Meaning $(z(s),w(s))=(\alpha_3(s),\alpha_4(s))$. So every point has the form $B_\theta(\alpha(s))$. But I think this is a bit too much handwaving and tells me nothing about the image being dense.

Comment: Do they assume that $S$ is connected? For otherwise the claim is false.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes, they assume connectedness

Comment: I assume that $\alpha(s)$ is a parameterized regular curve in the Lorentzian space. A way to solve this problem is to show that the action of $G$ on your surface is proper; that will imply that $S\to S/B$ is a principal $G$-bundle, which then has to be trivial, from which you will conclude the claimed parameterization. For instance, do you also know that the surface is contained in the (open) future (or past) light cone? (The action of $G$ on the open future/past cones is proper.)

Comment: I know the definition of a $G$-bundle but I never studied it in much details, so I don't see how $S/G$ (you meant $S/G$ instead of $S/B$, right?) being trivial gives that parametrization. The surface is not contained in the light cone, but it is contained in the region $\{ (x,y,z,w) \mid |x|>|y| \quad\mbox{and}\quad x>0 \}$, is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, their claim is true and you should absolutely learn more about bundles (vector bundles, principal bundles, connections, curvature, etc. I just do not see how you can study the modern GR without this).

Here are steps of the proof. You first observe that the action of $G$ on the region $Q=\{(x,y,z,w): |x|>|y|\}$ is **proper**: For every compact $K\subset Q$ the subset
$$
G_K:= \{g\in G: gK\cap K\ne \emptyset\}\subset G
$$ 
is compact. To prove this it suffices to analyze the 2D case, i.e. the action of $G$ on the intersection of $Q$ with the xy-plane and observe that the restriction of the Lorentzian metric to the quadrants $|x|>|y|$ in the xy-plane is definite (invariant under $G$, of course); then the claim follows e.g. from the Arzela-Ascoli theorem (since any group of isometries forms an equicontinuous family).

Since they assume that $S$ is contained in $Q$, it follows that the $G$-action on $S$ is also proper.

The next step is to quote a theorem about $G$-bundles: Let $X$ be a smooth manifold, $G\times X\to X$ a free smooth proper action of a Lie group (free means that for each $x\in X$, $gx=x$ implies that $g=e$) determines a principal $G$-bundle $X\to B=G/X$ (in particular, $B$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $dim(X)-dim(G)$).

Specializing to out case, $G\cong ({\mathbb R}, +)$, $X$ is a connected surface $S$, hence, $B$ is a connected 1-dimensional manifold, i.e. $B$ is either diffeomorphic to $S^1$ or to ${\mathbb R}$. (I do not think the former case can occur, but let's not worry about this.) In particular, the group $G$ is contractible. It is a general fact about bundles that a fiber bundle with contractible fibers has a section, so we obtain a section $s: B\to X$. By the definition of a section of a principal bundle, $g s(B)\cap  s(B)\ne \emptyset$ if and only if $g=e$. Hence, we obtain an injective  differentiable map $G\times B\to X$, $(g,b)\mapsto g s(b)$. By the equality of the dimensions of the domain and the range, this map is open, hence, a diffeomorphism to its image. It is also clear that this map is surjective (since the bundle is principal, $G$ acts transitively on its fibers). Hence, the bundle $X\to B$ is trivial. This diffeomorphism also gives you the required parameterization of your surface $S$, since you can parameterize the base $B$, and, hence, $s(B)\subset S$, by $\alpha: I\to s(B)$, where $I$ is an interval in ${\mathbb R}$ and the image of $\alpha$ is either the entire $s(B)$ (if the latter is not diffeomorphic to the circle) or an open and dense subset of $s(B)$ (if the latter is diffeomorphic to the circle).

Comment: +1, thanks a lot for the effort, the argument seems really sound. I will wait just a bit before accepting the answer in case a simpler solution pops up - I find it curious that the authors would skip that much details about something like this in a more calculation-oriented paper.

Comment: @IvoTerek: Since this is a physics paper, I am not at all surprised that they did not include a proof: For most physicists, a "proof" is a calculation. (And I am not at all sure that the authors of the paper could produce a rigorous proof of the claim if someone had asked them.) As an aside: The circle case for $B$ does not occur (and this is not hard to show), so the image of the above parameterization is the entire surface $S$.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something more pedestrian: following the paper's notation, put $\mathcal{P} = \{(x,0,z,w) \mid x>0\}$.

For each $p \in S$ there is a unique $\theta(p) \in \Bbb R$ such that $B_{\theta(p)}(p) \in S \cap \mathcal{P}$. This also defines a continuous map $\theta\colon S \to \Bbb R$. Now, $f\colon S \to \Bbb L^4$ given by $f(p) = B_{\theta(p)}(p)$ is continuous and its image is precisely $S \cap \mathcal{P}$. Since the dimension of the intersection $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ is $1$ and $S$ connected now implies $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ connected (path-connected actually), we have that $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ is diffeomorphic either to $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb S^1$. Take a global parametrization $\alpha$ and define $X$ by that formula, done. If $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, then $\Sigma_\alpha$ will be all of $S$. In the other case, to consider parametrizations only with open domains, take a parametrization of $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ omitting a single point - in this case $\Sigma_\alpha$ is a proper open dense subset of $S$.

---

By the way, it seems that the latter case is impossible. If this were the case, the compactness of $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ would give up a timelike vector tangent to $S \cap \mathcal{P}$, since we can see $S \cap \mathcal{P}$ as a curve in $\Bbb L^3$.

Comment: Your argument contains a chain of unproven claims and confusion between continuous and differentiable, homeomorphic and diffeomorphic.

Comment: I forgot to come here. I filled up some details, the most important one being the proof that $S\cap \mathcal{P}$ is smooth. I managed to write it with a language a bit more accessible (in the context I am writing) but it boiled down to use the action of $G$, and the ideas you presented in your answer were useful, so I'm accepting it now